# ImportError: No module named 'mongoengine.django'

Tags: django, python-3.x, mongoengine

i've been looking everywhere for a solution to this.

i'm strapping mongo to django using `mongoengine`, and even though i have it connecting to mongo just fine (no auth), whenever i attempt to actually use it (creating a document), i get the dreaded:

> ImportError: No module named 'mongoengine.django

message from the server.  i've uninstalled and installed `mongoengine==0.9.0` and `pymongo` several times, and managed to get it to connect, but no love on doing anything.

(running MacOS 10.10, django 1.9.2 and python 3.5)

thanks guys

Comment: Show us the traceback please.

Answer (score 3):

As the offical site says, main MongoEngine repository do not support django like before, except 0.9 version. The development team turn to develop django-mongoengine. http://docs.mongoengine.org/django.html